# How can I securely publish WinRM / PowerShellRemoting commands over the Internet?

Tags: powershell, security, office365, powershell-remoting, winrm

Office 365, and [Exchange Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335083(v=exchg.160).aspx) both expose powershell to the internet via HTTPS.

When this is done, only a subset of possible commandlets are downloaded for remote execution.

How can I publish a specific list of powershell commands (some which I produced) over HTTPS?

Comment: Are you looking for [Just Enough Administration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn896648.aspx)?

Comment: @BenH OMG that is Awesome! I'm surprised, and happy this exists. I'm just hoping that it's intended to be consumer facing (on the Net) like O365.  I'm ready for some surprises / restrictions on intended use.